# What does "adic" mean?

Tags: terminology

The word "adic" is often seen in books of algebra and number theory. I don't know what does this word mean, so I look it up in a dictionary, called *Oxford Dictionary of English*. But it does not appear there.

So what does this word mean just as a word, and why is it used in defining the mathematical concepts?

I am sorry if this question seems weird. English is not mother language.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I always thought it was a suffix *-adic* not a word. As for what it means exactly, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Dan This does not appear in the dictionary I mentioned, neither as a word, nor as a suffix.

Comment: might be coming from dyad, triad (wilde guess)

Comment: It *might* have some German ties, as that seems to be (according to MathWorld) the language used by the first person to "come up" with the concept of p-adic numbers.

Comment: @anorton Thank you. I guess if this is the case, then "p-adic" might be created by someone who wanted to translate "p-adische" into English.

Comment: I always assumed, like user8268, that it was by analogy with *dyadic*, *triadic*, *tetradic*, etc. Make the root number a variable, $p$, and there you go.

Answer (score 6):

The OED Online has an [entry for -adic](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240374?redirectedFrom=-adic#eid).

The first definition relates to chemistry, while the second and third definitions relate to mathematics:

Second definition:

> ***Math.*** With preceding symbol or numeral (esp. the generalized symbol p, denoting a prime number), forming adjectives designating numbers expressible as a sequence of digits in the base represented by the symbol (or as a power series in this quantity).

Third definition:

> Chiefly ***Math.*** and ***Logic.*** With preceding symbol (usu. n), forming adjectives designating a function, operator, relation, etc., having the number of arguments represented by the given symbol. Cf. -ary suffix1 Additions.

(Accessed 12/4/14, 11:03am)

Comment: I don't have access to the link (it redirects to the homepage). You should copy the excerpt as a quote to make it self-contained. But who am I to complain.

Comment: @AlexR: Now I can't access it either! Strange -- it worked when I posted it.

Comment: @anorton: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: As listed in the OED, the etymology is from the two suffixes -ad and -ic, where the suffix -ad means "forming collective numerals" and is the same suffix that appears in "olympiad."

Comment: The third definition is also seen in programming, especially for [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)